# Best practice for struct layout in C/C++

Tags: c, memory-alignment

I have read articles and SO answers about how we can cutoff compiler added padding if we layout the structs in the decreasing order of size of independent fields.

eg: Instead of laying out (L1) the struct like this

```
   typedef struct dummy {
   char         c1;
   short        s1;
   int          i1;
   unsigned int ui1;
   double       d1;
   } dummy_t;
```

create the layout (L2) like this

```
   typedef struct dummy {
   double       d1;   
   unsigned int ui1;
   int          i1;
   short        s1;
   char         c1;   
   } dummy_t;
```

My question here is, are there scenarios where layout L2 has downsides when compared to L1 or any other layout ? Or can I take it into my design rules to always use L2 ? Also is the natural alignment rule

```
natural alignment = sizeof(T)
```

always true for primitive types ?

Comment: C & C++ are distinct languages and struct in C is something different than in C++. in C++ struct is generalized to class. Choose your language.

Comment: I was talking from C PoV. However I believe alignment and padding still applies to C++ structs and classes for member variables ?

Comment: @RohitMat -  Yes, alignment and padding are applicable to C++ struct and class types.   However, access control comes into play, and can affect the order of members, and therefore padding.  So good practice in C++ - however that is measured - can well be different from good practice in C.   If you are talking from a C PoV, I therefore suggest removing the C++ tag.

Comment: @Peter, I'll remove the tag. Thanks

Comment: @P__J__ A valid `struct` in C will generally have the same memory layout when compiled as C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wonder about alignement/structure size only if you are running on a memory constrained system (you want to limit the size of each element). This makes sense only for systems/designs where you know you will store a lot of such structure and used storage space is an issue. On the other hand grouping the content of a structure logically can bring clarity to your code. I would always favor clarity against performance, especially at early design phases. Even more if you do not have performance related constraints.

About performance it might happen that accessing "random" content from L2 is worse than from L1 because memory cache alignement constraints can also come into play. (eg accessing in a row 2 elements of struct L1 can be slower or quicker than 2 elements of L2). For such optimization, profiling is the only way to know which layout is the best.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective on clarity. I'm working on systems with memory constraints and hence had to ask this question. In terms on caching, I'm not sure if I got your point. Do you mean cases where an object from L1 or L2 exceeds a cache line and impacts the performance due to accessing of the field outside the line ?

Comment: Hello. Yes depending on the alignement of the structure itself and its own size against cache line size (does it fit in a cache line?) accessing 2 elements in a row might have a cache penalty or not depending of their respective "distance" in the cache line. It will be beneficial to have your struct fit to a cache line whenever it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

> My question here is, are there scenarios where layout L2 has downsides when compared to L1 or any other layout ?

Sometimes you need to have members in a different order. Reasons for this may include:

- The structure is part of a communications protocol and has to be sent byte-by-byte across a network or other communication device. In this case, the layout of the structure may be dictated by the protocol, and you will have to match it exactly (including padding or lack thereof).
- The structure is part of a family of structures that share initial sequences of members, so those members must be placed first. This is sometimes done to allow structures to be handled in a “generic” way by operating on those initial members only.
- The structure includes a buffer whose length will vary (by being allocated dynamically according to needs that arise during program execution). Such a buffer is implemented with a flexible array member, which must be the last member in the structure.

Also, there may be incidental effects of how members are ordered. For example, if member `x` happens to be used much more frequently than other members of the structure, putting it at the front might allow the compiler to access it with simpler address arithmetic, since its offset from the beginning of the structure will be zero. This is rarely a consideration in programming, but I mention it for completeness.

Aside such considerations, you are generally free to order members as you desire.

> Also is the natural alignment rule `natural alignment = sizeof(T)` always true for primitive types ?

No. As an example, an eight-byte `long` might have an alignment require of one, two, four, or eight bytes.

> … we can cutoff compiler added padding if we layout the structs in the decreasing order of size of independent fields.

This is not true for members that are aggregates (arrays, structures, and unions). Consider that a member `char x[13];` is 13 bytes in size but only requires alignment of one byte. To minimize padding, order members in order of decreasing alignment requirement, not decreasing size.

Comment: " order members in order of decreasing alignment requirement, not decreasing size". Thanks Eric. This makes sense

Answer (score 1):

IMO abstracting from the implementation details like caching (which is too broad to be discussed in the post answer) there is no difference.

The difference is if you place the variable sized (or zero sized) object at the end of the struct (example):

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    char data[];
}string;

string *create(size_t size)
{
    string *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) + size);
    if(ptr)
    {
        ptr -> size = size;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

If course the logical member order (and potential packing) is required if struct will store some received binary data (for example communication packet header)